# How to specify a callback/listener in an interface

Tags: android

I am looking for an example of an interface with a listener, so any class implementing the interface also needs to have the listener. For the interface below I wanted to have a listener to callback when the ImageView is loaded. One class will use a bitmap, the other will use a uri. In either case

**My interface**

```
public interface ITokenMessageService {

     public void sendAcknowledgement();
     public void sendReceived();
     public void sendFinished();
     public void displayToken(ImageView imageView, [here is where I want the callback]);

}
```

This may seem rather simple but the queries for interface returned a lot of UX responses and because you implement an interface for a listener, there were a lot of responses for that as well, so I was having trouble finding an example.

Comment: I would suggest reviewing and updating your question for clarity, perhaps with an example of what you're trying to achieve. I read your question 3 times and have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface ITokenMessageService {

     public void sendAcknowledgement();
     public void sendReceived();
     public void sendFinished();
     public void displayToken(ImageView imageView, YourCallback callback );

     //You could have a get function in your interface
     //thus anything implementing it, needs to have a function that returns
     //the callback, ie it has it. 
     public YourCallback getYourCallback();
}
```

In reality this doesn't make much sense though, as why would you need to guarantee the implementer also has the callback through an `Interface`? If its using the `displayToken` function it **HAS** to have it or have access to it anyways, its a moot point.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I have a class which is going to reference the ITokenMessageService interface. The two services are will implement displayToken, one using a bitmap, the other using picasso/uri. Both do it differently, but in either case I need to listen for the response and take action. This mean, as I understand it, the interface needs to require a listener be passed in and that listener needs to be defined.

Comment: `displayToken` accepts the *`callback(interface)`* as it's second argument. You are already passing it in. You are not making any sense.